# ArrayList confusion

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, java.util.scanner

The code below is my attempt to read from a file of strings, read through each line until a ':' is found then store + print everything after that. however The print function prints out everything that I read in from the file. Can someone spot where I'm going wrong? thanks

edit: every line is in this format "Some text here:More text here"

```
public void openFile() {

        try {
            scanner = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("calendar.ics"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not open file");

        }

    }

    public void readFile() {
        ArrayList<String> vals = new ArrayList<String>();
        String test;

        try {
        while ((line = scanner.readLine()) != null)
        {

        int indexOfComma = line.indexOf("\\:"); // returns firstIndexOf ':'
        test = line.substring(indexOfComma+1);  // test to be everything after ':'
        vals.add(test);  // add values to vals
        }
        }  catch(Exception ex){ }

            for(int i=0; i<vals.size(); i++){
         System.out.println(vals.get(i));
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to escape your colon.

```
line.indexOf("\\:");
```

Change the above line to: -

```
line.indexOf(":");
```

Because, that will search for `\\:`, and if not found return the value `-1`.

```
test = line.substring(indexOfComma+1);
```

So, if your `indexComma` is `-1`, which will certainly be, if your string does not contain - `\\:`, then your above line becomes: -

```
line.substring(0);  // same as whole string
```

---

As a suggestion, you should have abstract type as the type of reference when declaring your list. So, you should use `List` instead of `ArrayList` on the LHS of the `List` declaration: -

```
List<String> vals = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Ha thanks that worked perfectly, I really should have known that. +1

Comment: @shanahobo86.. Actually not everything you know from beginning. You automatically know it when time comes. You're welcome though :)

Comment: Thats true. Sometimes I'm angry with myself for not spotting these mistakes and coming to StackOverFlow for help. I try to remind myself that this is a learning curve, someday maybe I'll be answering questions instead of asking :-) thanks for your input

Comment: @shanahobo86.. Yay. I like your confidence. Good luck. and enjoy coding. I hope to see you some day giving very good answers on SO. :)

Comment: Another option would be to use split on ":"

Comment: @Cruncher.. Yeah that can be done. But it is not actually required a create another array, as OP just wants the string after first `:`, nothing else.